# How to stack all numpy array elements in a list and combine to one numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of numpy arrays, each array being one dimension horizontally and having different vertical sizes. An example:

```
[[  0]
 [  1]
 [  2]
 [  3]
 [  4]
 [  5]
 [  6]
 [  7]
 [  8]
 [  9]
 [ 10]]
```

I have a list of arrays like this; however, I want a single array that is based off the previous array. For example if I had two of the exact same arrays as the one above in a list, the desired output would be:

```
[[  0]
 [  1]
 [  2]
 [  3]
 [  4]
 [  5]
 [  6]
 [  7]
 [  8]
 [  9]
 [ 10]
 [ 11]
 [ 12]
 [ 13]
 [ 14]
 [ 15]
 [ 16]
 [ 17]
 [ 18]
 [ 19]
 [ 20]]
```

All arrays have different vertical lengths, but they are all one dimension horizontally. They all contain different integers, and they're not always in a specific order.

Comment: it's unclear, if you have twice the same array you would still want the second part to be in the range 11->20?

Comment: Yes. Basically take the last integer from the previous array and add that all to the next array, then repeat for all arrays. It's a bit hard to explain, so sorry if I'm not being detailed enough. Basically each array contains indices, but none of the arrays are based on each other. They're in order, but they're not based on the previous array. For example, each array starts at 0 or around zero, but it should start where the previous array left off.

Comment: @Uft6tZqX Do you use the updated array to get the next start value? So for example, array A ends in 10, array B ends in 15, and array C ends in 7, would you add 10 to Array B and 25 to array C? Or would you add 10 to array B and 15 to array C?

Comment: Yes, I would use the updated version of the previous array. The starting integer of an array should always be equal to or greater than the last integer from the previous array.

Answer (score 0):

Start with an empty array `tot` and copy the first array into it. Then, add the last element of `tot` to all elements of the next array and insert it into `tot`. Repeat until no remaining arrays exist.

```
import numpy as np
 
A = [[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]]

A = np.array(A)
tot = A.copy()

# Assume only 1 remaining array
for i in range(1):
    arr = [[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]]
    arr = np.array(arr) + tot[-1] + 1
    tot = np.append(tot, arr, axis=0)
```

This gives what you want:

```
print(tot)
[[ 0]
 [ 1]
 [ 2]
 [ 3]
 [ 4]
 [ 5]
 [ 6]
 [ 7]
 [ 8]
 [ 9]
 [10]
 [11]
 [12]
 [13]
 [14]
 [15]
 [16]
 [17]
 [18]
 [19]
 [20]
 [21]]
```